# MongoDB Aggregate function for returning day wise count for a particular date range

Tags: node.js, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I need to get the count of individual users for a particular date range that too on each day basis. Let's say, there are a total of 100 users within a month (1st - 30th), I need to get the count like

```
{
    1st - 2 users
    2nd - 10 users
}

MessagesSchema.statics.totalMessagesGraph = (id, startDate, endDate, platform) => {
    return Messages.aggregate([
        {
            $match: {
                id: id,
                platform: platform,
                timestamp: {
                    $gte: new Date(startDate),
                    $lte: new Date(endDate)
                }
            }
        }    
    ])
}
```

What should be here to get the desired result ?

**Expected Result:**

For that particular date ranges the count for each day.

```
{
    date1 - 20,
    date2 - 22,
    date3 - 24,
    ...
    date30 - 12 
}
```

The expected output should look like above. What query should be proceeded after `$match`. If possible please take a sample dataset and provide the output.

Comment: @Adeel Thanks for the edit. I was in a hurry. Apologies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use **$group** to get day wise count
for example

```
db.collection.aggregate([
         {
            $match: {
                //id: id,
                //platform: platform,
                //timestamp: {
                    //$gte: new Date(startDate),
                    //$lte: new Date(endDate)
                //}
            //}
            // Your matching logic
          },
          /* Now grouping users based on _id or id parameter for each day 
          from the above match results.

          $createdAt can be replaced by date property present in your database. 
          */
          { $group : {
                id : { day: { $dayOfMonth: "$createdAt" },
                        month: { $month: "$createdAt" }, 
                        year: { $year: "$createdAt" } },
                        count : {$sum : 1} 
                }
           }
        ])
```

Based on this you will get output like :

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "day" : 14,
        "month" : 1,
        "year" : 2017
    },
    "count" : 2.0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "day" : 31,
        "month" : 1,
        "year" : 2017
    },
    "count" : 8.0
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "day" : 2,
        "month" : 1,
        "year" : 2017
    },
    "count" : 4.0
}

...
```

You can use the above query results to get required output.

More precisely you can remove month and year parameters from group query to get output like :

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "day" : 25
    },
    "count" : 7.0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "day" : 18
    },
    "count" : 4.0
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "day" : 17
    },
    "count" : 4.0
}
...
```

For reference you can check the mongoDB documentation also refer this.

[MongoDB Aggregation Queries for "Counts Per Day"](https://dzone.com/articles/mongodb-aggregation-queries-for-counts-per-day-par)

Hope above example help you in getting the required output.

Comment: Thanks for the solution @arpan. But this isn't what the expected output which I was looking for. After few trials got the solution on the same day. Please look into the solution which I've posted below

Comment: Yes, you can do in any of these two ways I was considering your format like day-1 : 20, day-2 : 30 ...

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution which I figured out after few trials.

```
            {
                '$project': {
                    timestamp: {'$dateToString': {format: '%Y-%m-%d', date: '$timestamp'}}                }
            }, {
                '$group': {
                    _id: {timestamp: '$timestamp'},
                    count: {'$sum': 1}
                }
            }
```

And here is the output

```
  "response": [
    {
      "_id": {
        "timestamp": "2019-01-08"
      },
      "count": 1
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "timestamp": "2019-01-13"
      },
      "count": 1
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "timestamp": "2019-01-16"
      },
      "count": 1
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "timestamp": "2019-01-17"
      },
      "count": 1
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "timestamp": "2019-01-19"
      },
      "count": 1
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "timestamp": "2019-02-01"
      },
      "count": 1
    }
  ]
```